How can I detect which hyperscaler is running my Kubernetes cluster?
I have to configure an application running on Kubernetes, and I do not have access to any hyperscaler-specific management infrastructure.
How can I figure out whether my cluster runs on one of the big three (Amazon, Azure, or Google GKE) using only kubectl with a valid KUBECONFIG file?

Note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

... and I have to solve this riddle programatically.

What will you do with this information once you have it?  IME there's not a lot of practical difference between, say, running on EKS vs. running on Minikube, beyond the size of application it's possible to run.

I'm currently in a situation where pods on Azure fail to start due to some inconsistencies with VM sizes/types and storage classes. This only happens on Azure, and I want to be prepared for it...

I found a technical solution: the node.spec.providerID field starts with the platform name.
kubectl get nodes -o jsonpath='{.items[].spec.providerID}'

returns <ProviderName>://<ProviderSpecificNodeID>.
See the definition of Node in the Kubernetes Specs.

Assuming (!) that your client is configured to access the cluster, you can infer the platform from the KUBECONFIG users section.
Each provider provides a unique auth mechanism to access the cluster.
For example, for GKE, the relevant user.exec.command value is gke-gcloud-auth-plugin.
KUBECONFIG contexts bind cluster to user values so, as kubectl does, for a specific cluster, use the context list to find the user and then use the user.exec.command to determine the platform.

Check the user.exec.command under users section. For EKS that would be aws, AKS is kubelogin. You may also encounter certificate data (eg. ACK). GKE as mentioned above is gke-gcloud-auth-plugin.

you can add the name of the cluster in your ~/.kube/config file for each cluster, and then retrieve it by
kubectl config view --minify -o jsonpath='{.clusters[].name}'


The cluster name is freely configurable; it may give a hint on the platform but often it doesn't.
